# How can I create custom Exchange 365 mail flow rules / mail processing?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

I'm beginning to find the EAC alittle limited in its capabilities and would like to create rules with a bit more functionality. Specifically, i'm trying to embed images into all outgoing messages as a way of working around the limitations of the disclaimer rule. There is pay-for services that can achieve this goal but I can foresee the ability to create custom rules having other applications too and I love a challenge!

I'm going to hazard a guess that Microsoft aren't going to be too happy about running programs on their lovely servers so am assuming that some kind of hybrid environment might be necessary. Or I was wondering if maybe there's a way of creating a rule which points to a server which hosts a program.

I'm really not sure where to start with this one so if anyone can point me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated. Mr Google hasn't been very helpful so far.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about adding the specified HTML(image link) to your disclaimer?
[image]

Applies the specified HTML disclaimer to the end of the message.
When you create or modify the rule in PowerShell, use the ApplyHtmlDisclaimerLocation parameter with the value Append.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using this method at the moment but the issue which i'm trying to get around is that the images don't appear (unless downloaded or the user is a trusted sender) due to being linked externally. I was hoping there was a way to add the image to the email in the same way that copying and pasting works (I believe that the base64 encoded image is embedded into the contents of the message somewhere although i am yet to find exactly where).

Comment: Sorry that have not found other possible workarounds so far. Seems we could only reach this step with Outlook & Exchange options alone.